# After Login Redirect to List Page

Tags: magento-1.9, list.phtml

I have create Custom login form. Copy default login.phtml file and create other login-details.phtml file.

Now in Product List page i want to Login Form After login Customer see products in listing. Now i set condition to check login with session its working fine but after login i want to redirect Product Listing page. Currently its redirect to My Account Dashboard.

Any one have solution for thi.

Comment: how would to determine which category list page you want to redirect after login ?

Comment: I want Current category page after login where i am login.

Comment: When you login with default login, check it will redirect on current page or redirect to my account ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento already has this feature to redirect customer to last visited page after logging in.

Go to `System` > `Configuration` > `Customer Configuration` > `Login Options` and set `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` to `No`.

If this option is turned off, it sets the `beforeAuthUrl` to the page you came from and in your case, it will be category page.

I hope it will work..